# What 50s/60s sci-fi movie ends with aliens/martians taking a child in their spaceship and destroying earth?

Tags: story-identification, movie

What '50s or '60s sci-fi movie ends with aliens/Martians taking a child in their spaceship and destroying earth?
This is live action.
Filmed in black and white.
I believe it is American made.
It is in English.
I saw it on Youtube maybe 5 years ago.

I've never seen a movie where the aliens win & destroy earth before this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  There really aren't many details here.  When did you see this?  Where?  What language was it in?  Live-action or animated?  What did the spaceship look like?  How did they destroy Earth?  Why?  Please [edit] your question and add as many details as you can possibly remember.

Comment: @user14111 You know how this works.  The 3 details OP remembers (and we usually grant that at least one might be wrong) won't necessarily be the same details anyone else recalls; we _always_ ask people if they can add anything else.

Comment: @user14111 I grant you your point, but if either of the 2 major points (blows up Earth at the end or kidnaps a child) is in error, and we don't know that it's a French-language cartoon (to pick a random possibility), then it would be almost impossible to answer.  Now we have a bit more information I'm happy reopening it.